# WCF AuthorizationManager not triggered when requesting metadata

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, wsdl, authorization

In the web.config of my WCF service I have the following section:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Company.Connection.Services.Security.MyAuthorizationManager, Company.Connection.Services" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I want to use the *CheckAccessCore* method of my *ServiceAuthorizationManager* to identify the user and decide if the user is allowed to obtain the WSDL, but the method is not hit if I request the metadata. Am I missing something in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have to name your behavior and use that name to link the behaviour to your service. e.g.

```
<system.serviceModel>  
  <services>  
    <service name="MyService"  
             behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">  
...

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behaviour name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
...
```

Comment: This does not help since an unnamed behavior is applied to the default service (although I tried it). I do get the WSDL but the CheckAccessCore method is not invoked.